How to express Variational Auto-Encoder, ELBO with Random Variables?
In the context of VAE, variational inference and Bayesian statistics more broadly the equations typically involve densities that are somewhat loosely defined. Often the notation refers to a probability density $p$ or $p_{\theta}$ but the probability space, and the random variables giving the concepts rigour are left out.
I found a fantastic post about the formal measure theoretic statement of Bayes Rule in this post:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/444080/a-measure-theoretic-formulation-of-bayes-theorem/444082#mjx-eqn-1
but translating this to topics like VAE is not straightforward for me.
From probability theory and stochastic calculus I'm used to work with random variables and their distributions rather than with 'anonymous' densities.
I struggle to understand the equations in variational autoencoder VAE, where e.g. we have for ELBO:
$$
\text{ELBO}(\theta, \phi| x) = 
   \mathbb{E}_{q_{\phi}(z | x)} [ \log  p_{\theta}(x | z)]
   - \text{D}_{KL} ( q_{\phi}(z | x) || p(z) )
$$
It would really help me to express the involved formulas in terms of random variables or vectors and I also wonder why this is not done typically.
So suppose $X$ follows the distribution of the data with a parametrised density $p_{\theta}$ and the latent r.v. $Z \sim q_{\phi}$, can I write the term of the r.h.s. of the equation for ELBO as a realisation of a conditional expectation
$$
\mathbb{E}_{q_{\phi}(z | x)} [ \; \log  p_{\theta}(x | z) \;] 
= \mathbb{E} [ \; \log  p_{\theta}(x | Z) \; | X =x]
$$
or do I misunderstand the meaning of the term?
